# FreeBSD: how to associate disk serial numbers to device names when using a 3ware SATA card

Tags: truenas, 3ware, freebsd

When using a 3ware SATA/RAID card is there a way to associate the disk serial # with the /dev/daN device? I can get serial numbers by using "smartctl -d 3ware,0 /dev/twa0 -i", but I don't know if "twa0" directly corresponds to "da0".  smartctl -a /dev/da0 just tells me that I need to use -d 3ware,N so I can't get the information directly that way.

The FreeNAS GUI does show the serial numbers of the disks once they are in a volume, so there should be some way of doing it beforehand. I need the device/serial mappings before I create the pool though because I want to make sure to mirror the disks across two 3ware sata cards.  I'd also like to be able to map physical slot locations to serial numbers and device names to make replacing drives easier in the future.

I'm running FreeBSD 8.2 (FreeNAS 8.0 RC5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the twaX to daX config look in dmesg.boot:

```
$ cat /var/run/dmesg.boot
da0 at twa0 bus 0 scbus0 target 0 lun 0
da0: <AMCC 9690SA-4I  DISK 4.10> Fixed Direct Access SCSI-5 device 
da0: 100.000MB/s transfers
da0: 476827MB (976541696 512 byte sectors: 255H 63S/T 60786C)
da1 at twa0 bus 0 scbus0 target 1 lun 0
```

For the 'can I get these before I build an array part':

On my FreeBSD boxes I install 3dm2:

```
$ pkg_info 3dm\* 
Information for 3dm-2.09.01.004_1,1:

Comment:
3ware RAID controller monitoring daemon and web server


Description:
3DM 2 provides a web interface to remotely create, manage and monitor
your 3ware RAID arrays. In the event of a hardware failure, 3DM 2 can
automatically notify you via email.

WWW: http://www.3ware.com/support/
```

Once you get 3dm2 setup you can login to the web interface and under Information::Drive Information it will have:

```
 Extra Drive Info (Controller ID 0 - VPort 0)
  Drive Type    SATA
  Serial #  9YY0XX4N
```

Comment: Any way to do that without installing 3dm?  I'm on a slimmed down box that acts as a storage appliance and I am reluctant to install new packages...